# Edit a text file using batch

Tags: batch-file, search, replace

I would like to edit a word in textfile1.txt if it is found in textfile2.txt

textfile1.txt contains

```
264392  ja_JP   9000    -0.2620 0   2   0   どれ
264393  ja_JP   9000    0.5577  0   2   0   最低
264394  ja_JP   9000    0.4761  0   2   0   明け
264395  ja_JP   9000    -0.1549 0   2   0   消費
264396  ja_JP   9000    -0.2028 0   2   0   ばな
264399  ja_JP   9000    -0.1141 0   2   0   覧下
```

textfile2.txt contains

```
264394  ja_JP   9000    0.4761  0   2   0   明け
264395  ja_JP   9000    -0.1549 0   2   0   消費
264396  ja_JP   9000    -0.2028 0   2   0   ばな
```

textfile1.txt should now be

```
264392  ja_JP   9000    -0.2620 0   2   0   どれ
264393  ja_JP   9000    0.5577  0   2   0   最低
#264394 ja_JP   9000    0.4761  0   2   0   明け
#264395 ja_JP   9000    -0.1549 0   2   0   消費
#264396 ja_JP   9000    -0.2028 0   2   0   ばな
264399  ja_JP   9000    -0.1141 0   2   0   覧下
```

only the number at the beginning of the line is important

I've searched for a few codes but it places the edited number on the bottom of the file not edit the file

thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is no way to "edit" a file with batch. You will have to read both input files line by line and write the output file line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does not require that the files have any sort order. It should work as long as `FOR /F` command correctly process Japanese characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read textfile2 and create an array with the first column
for /F %%a in (textfile2.txt) do set "file2[%%a]=1"

rem Process textfile1
(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (textfile1.txt) do (
   if defined file2[%%a] set /P "=#" < NUL
   echo %%a %%b
)) > textfile1.new

move /Y textfile1.new textfile1.txt > NUL
```

Comment: thanks it works! but it reads textfile2.txt on the second line so i have to enter it first but still it works thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both files are already sorted as shown in your example, no file contains the `!` character, and the 2nd column is always present.

Assuming FOR /F handles the Japanese characters properly (I simply don't know), then the following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "B="
<"textfile2.txt" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("textfile1.txt") do (
    if not defined B (
      set /p "B="
      for /f %%B in ("!B! x") do set "B=%%B"
    )
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%C in ("%%A") do if !B! equ %%C (
      echo #%%C %%D 
      set "B="
    ) else (
      echo %%A
    )
  )
) >"textfile1.txt.new"
move /y "textfile1.txt.new" "textfile1.txt" >nul
```

The above is a variation of a technique used to merge two sorted text files.